# Why is gradle telling me "error: release version 8 not supported"?

Tags: java, gradlew

I'm trying to compile [a Java program](https://github.com/Anuken/Mindustry/) using `gradlew`, but I am stuck on the error:

```
$ ./gradlew core:compileJava
No Android SDK found. Skipping Android module.

> Configure project :
Compiling with build: 'custom build'

> Configure project :desktop
Scheduling sprite packing.

> Task :core:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'.
> error: release version 8 not supported

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I've tried `--info` and `--debug` but I can't tell what's causing the error. It *sounds* as if it's trying to compile with Java 8, but I have no clue how that's happening. The only JDKs I have installed are `java-17-openjdk-17.0.9.0.9-1.fc39.x86_64` and `java-latest-openjdk-21.0.1.0.12-1.rolling.fc39.x86_64`.

Where and why am I (apparently) getting Java 8 from, and how can I tell what actual command is causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out myself, but I'm going to post anyway because it confused the ever-loving snot out of me, and I couldn't find any useful information elsewhere. Also, this doesn't answer the "how do I figure out why this is broken?" part of my Question, and I'd still appreciate that information.

---

It turns out the problem is that `java` is coming from `java-17-openjdk`, but `javac` was coming from `java-latest-openjdk-devel`... and, because `gradlew` was in places invoking JDK 17 specifically, who knows what `javac` it was actually trying to use.

Anyway, the reason my system was set up like that is because tons of things depend on JDK 17, whereas `java-latest-openjdk-devel` is the obvious thing to install when one wants to build things that use Java.

So, the moral of the story is, check that `java --version` and `javac --version` report the same thing, and in particular, in case of weird `gradlew` failures, make sure to know what `java` it's using and that the corresponding `javac` is installed.